# Publish Over FTP in Jenkins dont send files

Tags: jenkins, ftp, publish

I have a C # application and am trying to publish via the Publish Over FTP plugin, but the files are not going.

```
    FTP: Connecting from host [STAFF01]
    FTP: Connecting with configuration [FTP de TESTE (CadastroUnicoteste)]   ...
   FTP: Disconnecting configuration [FTP de TESTE (CadastroUnico teste)] ...
   FTP: Transferred 0 file(s)
   Finished: SUCCESS
```

if you change the syntax as suggested elsewhere in the forum, the error changes to:

```
    Tempo Decorrido 00:00:20.94
FTP: Connecting from host [STAFF01]
FTP: Connecting with configuration [FTP de TESTE (CadastroUnico teste)] ...
FTP: Disconnecting configuration [FTP de TESTE (CadastroUnico teste)] ...
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exception when changing to FTP directory [CadastroUnico/CadastroUnico.Classes/Aplicacao]]
Build step 'Send build artifacts over FTP' changed build result to UNSTABLE
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

At System configuration (Global config), i test the FTP address and it's OK!

I need to send all the files via ftp that are in the folder:C:\Jenkins\workspace\Cadastro_Unico_Cliente\CadastroUnico\CadastroUnico

...so in the project configuration I put:

```
Source files: **/CadastroUnico/CadastroUnico/*
Remove prefix: 
Remote directory:
```

My expectation was that all the files in the specified folder went to the configured FTP address.

Comment: Do you need to change directory the other end before you can put anything across? If so, you need to set the 'Remote directory'. Try it manually first.

Comment: Yes, my project has several directories that it needs to send via FTP. I did a manual test here, it only copies the files if all the folders already exist in the FTP directory.

How would he create the folders when sending?

Comment: Hello, I got the same error returned "Exception when changing to FTP directory". I set **verbose: true** to see what FTP commands was used and there is no MKDIR but only a CWD to the directory where to put the files which not exists on the server! Why MKDIR is not done?

Answer (score 0):

Just put below line in source file - `\CadastroUnico\CadastroUnico\* and in remove prefix put line - \CadastroUnico\CadastroUnico`

and run the build